# Слетают nuget пакеты

Tags: visual-studio, azure, nuget

Скачал проект с azure repos. Пробовал и средствами студии и просто скачивал архив. В разных модулях ругается на отсутствие различных nuget пакетов, не всех а именно некоторых. Хотя ссылка на них присутствует и сами пакеты в папке packages имеются. После удаления проблемного пакета и повторной его установки ошибка исчезает. Кто сталкивался с подобным глюком?
Ссылки на битые пакеты при этом со странным треугольником... Это, наверное, студия так сигнализирует, что не видит их?

[image: Ссылки]

Answer (score 0):

В ньюгет консоле `Update-Package -reinstall`

Comment: Не сработало. Какие то пакеты не хотят переустанавливаться, вылетает с ошибкой.

Comment: Давай текст ошибки сюда.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло следующее - очистка папки packages и запуск восстановления пакетов nuget